# does pyspark.ml provide ways to calculate bic for Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: python, apache-spark

In sklearn we can compare Gaussian Mixture Model based on BIC.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.bic

Is there a similar way in pyspark.ml to use a metric to select optimal number of cluster for Gaussian Mixture Model?

Comment: Hello. Any update?